# Image on the edge of container in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to put the Image on the edge of the container in flutter

As in shown in image

[image: img]

Comment: If you want a car image to overlap on blue container as above image you mention,. ... You should use a stack widget with positioned widget on container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: demo]

```
Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 135,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Image.network(
                      "https://pngimg.com/uploads/mercedes/mercedes_PNG80135.png",
                      height: 125,
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(width: 30,),

                    FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: (){},
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward,color: Colors.black,),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a stack widget where the children of the stack would be the container and the image wrapped in a positioned widget.